# Computed Visible property based on field value xpages

Tags: xpages

I am new to xpages and trying to teach myself as I go along. I am trying to learn how to do a computed visible property to hide an object based on the presence of whether a multi valued field contains a string. The classic notes hide when formula would be !@Contains(Display; "SomeValue") How would I do this in xpages SSJS. Thank you very much for any assistance for a new guy.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    pageTitle="Corporate Policy">
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td rendered="false">

            </xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText value="#{document1.Display}"
                    id="display">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Close" id="button1"
        style="margin-left:5.0px;margin-right:5.0px;margin-bottom:10.0px;margin-top:5.0px">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="true" save="false">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" formName="Policy"
            action="openDocument">
        </xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:this.navigationRules>
        <xp:navigationRule outcome="xsp-success"
            viewId="/bcbsarequirements.xsp">
        </xp:navigationRule>
    </xp:this.navigationRules>

    <xp:button value="Edit Document" id="button2" style="margin-right:5.0px;margin-bottom:10.0px;margin-top:5.0px"><xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
    <xp:this.action>
        <xp:changeDocumentMode mode="autoEdit" var="document1"></xp:changeDocumentMode>
    </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:panel style="height:auto;padding-left:5.0px;padding-right:5.0px;width:auto;padding-top:5.0px">
        <xp:panel
            style="background-color:rgb(192,192,192);text-align:center;font-weight:bold;font-size:12pt;font-style:italic;width:100%;height:25px;padding-top:3.0px;border-color:rgb(0,0,0);border-style:solid;border-width:medium">
            Corporate Policy
        </xp:panel>
        <xp:panel style="height:auto;border-color:rgb(128,128,128);width:100%;border-style:solid;margin-top:5.0px">
            <xp:table style="width:98%">
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td
                        style="border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);width:121.0px">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Name:" id="name_Label1"
                            for="name1" style="width:80.0px;font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td
                        style="border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;width:210.0px">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.Name}"
                            id="name1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Number" id="nbr_Label1"
                            for="nbr1" style="width:99.0px">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.Nbr}"
                            id="nbr1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td
                        style="background-color:rgb(233,233,233);width:121.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:label value="Effective Date:"
                            id="effectiveDate_Label1" for="effectiveDate1"
                            style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.EffectiveDate}"
                            id="effectiveDate1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Owner:"
                            id="respParty_Label1" for="respParty1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.RespParty}"
                            id="respParty1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td
                        style="background-color:rgb(233,233,233);width:121.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:label value="Revision Date:"
                            id="revisionDate_Label1" for="revisionDate1"
                            style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.RevisionDate}"
                            id="revisionDate1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Executive Sponsor"
                            id="execSp_Label1" for="execSp1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.ExecSp}"
                            id="execSp1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:121.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:label value="Category:" id="category_Label1"
                            for="category1" style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.Category}"
                            id="category1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Committee Approval Date:"
                            id="cmApprDate_Label1" for="cmApprDate1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.CmApprDate}"
                            id="cmApprDate1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:121.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:label value="Sub Category:"
                            id="subCategory_Label1" for="subCategory1" style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.SubCategory}"
                            id="subCategory1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Last Reviewed Date:"
                            id="lastRevDt_Label1" for="lastRevDt1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.LastRevDt}"
                            id="lastRevDt1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:121.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;background-color:rgb(233,233,233)">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Status:"
                            id="polStatus_Label1" for="polStatus1" style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.PolStatus}"
                            id="polStatus1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Review Frequency:"
                            id="reviewFreq_Label1" for="reviewFreq1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.ReviewFreq}"
                            id="reviewFreq1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td style="width:121.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:label value="Inactive Date:"
                            id="inactDate_Label1" for="inactDate1" style="font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:210.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.InactDate}"
                            id="inactDate1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td style="width:16.0px"></xp:td>
                    <td style="width:148.0px;background-color:rgb(233,233,233);border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin;font-weight:bold">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Owner E-mail Address:"
                            id="respEmail_Label1" for="respEmail1">
                        </xp:label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:234.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:dotted;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputText value="#{document1.RespEmail}"
                            id="respEmail1">
                        </xp:inputText>
                    </td>
                </xp:tr>







            </xp:table>
            <xp:br></xp:br>
            <xp:table style="width:99.0%;padding-left:5.0px;padding-right:5.0px">
                <xp:tr>

                    <xp:td style="width:718.0px">
                        <xp:label value="Policy Statement:"
                            id="polStmt_Label1" for="polStmt1"
                            style="font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold;color:rgb(0,0,128)">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin;padding-top:2.0px;padding-bottom:2.0px">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolStmt}"
                            id="polStmt1" style="width:98%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Policy Rationale:"
                            id="polRat_Label1" for="polRat1"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-weight:bold;font-size:10pt">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin;padding-right:15.0px;padding-top:2.0px;padding-bottom:0.0px">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolRat}"
                            id="polRat1" style="width:98.0%">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Policy Scope:"
                            id="polScope_Label1" for="polScope1"
                            style="font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,128);font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin;padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolScope}"
                            id="polScope1" style="width:98.0%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Policy Guide:"
                            id="polGuide_Label1" for="polGuide1"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolGuide}"
                            id="polGuide1" style="width:98.0%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Associated Procedures:"
                            id="polProc_Label1" for="polProc1"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolProc}"
                            id="polProc1" style="width:98%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Monitoring:" id="polMon_Label1"
                            for="polMon1"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolMon}"
                            id="polMon1" style="width:98%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label value="Definitions:"
                            id="polDef_Label1" for="polDef1"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolDef}"
                            id="polDef1" style="height:auto;width:98.0%">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:label id="polDef_Label2" for="polDef2"
                            style="color:rgb(0,0,128);font-size:10pt;font-weight:bold">
                            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[Links & References:]]></xp:this.value>
                        </xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">
                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolDef}"
                            id="polDef2" style="width:98%;height:auto">
                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td>

                        <xp:label value="Relevant Governance Standards:"
                            id="polStds_Label1" for="polStds1"
                            style="font-size:10pt;color:rgb(0,0,128);font-weight:bold">

                        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:!@Contains(getComponent("display").getValue(), "RGStandards")}]]></xp:this.rendered></xp:label>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xp:td
                        style="padding-left:15.0px;padding-right:15.0px;border-color:rgb(192,192,192);border-style:solid;border-width:thin">

                        <xp:inputRichText value="#{document1.PolStds}"
                            id="polStds1" style="height:auto;width:98%">

                        </xp:inputRichText>
                    </xp:td>
                </tr>











            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

The values are for example
"Rationale"
"AssocProc"
"Definition"
"Link"

Comment: Looks like you still have the !-sign there. So it's not visible when "display" control contains "RGStandards". Is that how it should be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Contains(getComponent("Display").getValue(), "SomeValue")
```

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth Thanks. In my understanding `getComponent("aa").getValue()` returns a string whereas Document level methods will return a Vector when the value is multi-value like in this case. (at)Contains takes a string parameter and I thought it would be easier for a XPage beginner to use these formula equivalents. I think one of the advantages of XPages is that we have different ways of accessing data to suit different needs.

Comment: I understand. I would propose to get value from datasource, but it has its own complications (getItemValue returns string for single value, and vector for multi value fields, what can be avoided by getItemValueArray, but this method does not work for other types but string; or to use SSJS snippet to handle this "feature"; or to access backend document, what may lead to some problems too).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I did add this to the control I was trying to toggle and when I do I get a 500 Error. I double checked the syntax.

Comment: Correction, I found this issue with the statement. It was the control I was trying to get value of. However, it is not hiding the control properly. Also, will this work if the control that I am trying to get value of is not visible. Currently it is, but for many users it is not.

Comment: OR you can try this... `var str = getComponent("Display").getValue();
var bol = str.indexOff("Some")>0?true:false`

Comment: @JimM Can you post your XPage source and the value you have in Display control. The Display control does not have to be visible. I removed "!" from my code because this is visible code, not hide/when code like on forms.

Comment: All sorted. I confused myself. I was thinking classic domino still that it is a hide / when, and now it is a visible when. Than you very much for helping me along. It is very appreciated